# IntelliJ shortcut to auto complete parameters for overloaded methods?

Tags: intellij-idea

If I have the following methods:

```
void foo(int one, int two, int three, int four){
   foo(|
}

void foo(int one, int two, int three, int four, int five) {
   // do something
}
```

And my cursor is where the `|` is at. Is there a shortcut to tell IntelliJ to autocomplete the parameters to pass into `foo(one, two, three, four, null)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

No special handling is needed, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will give you the completion shown above.
All you have to do is to select your expected completion.

Comment: On Android Studio for Mac this just opens spotlight (CMD+Space)?

Comment: How do you switch between the completions? If you press arrows, they will simply disappear.

Comment: @user3738870 if so, use a mouse

Comment: It's not clickable for me